# how to mimic request and response objects in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I was wondering if there is a way to mimic request and response objects in nodejs?

I tried,

```
request = {} // what next?
request.send = function(..) ?
```

I cannot use other libraries like nock, so was wondering how to mock it out?

Thanks!

Comment: This definitely requires clarification. What do you mean by request and response objects? Mimiced from what use, where?

Comment: i think is called mocking instead of "mimic"